# Pass id from HTML email to landing page, then use that to populate SQL query

Tags: php, sql, pdo, html-email

I have, let's say 5 email threads (a, b, c, d, e), each email is different. Each email contains a link to a landing page.

Then I have a php landing page wire frame that pulls data from a SQL database (currently mysql, but may change so using PDO) to populate different content depending on which email thread the viewer comes from. So 1 php landing page, but 5 rows in the database to populate 5 different versions of that landing page depending on which email viewer links from.

My current query in my landing page looks like this:

```
<?php
       $result = "SELECT body_copy FROM low_engagement WHERE thread_segment = 'a3'";
       $stmt = $connection->prepare($result);
       $stmt->execute();
       $body_copy = "";
       while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
       $bodyCopy = $row['body_copy'];
       }
?>
```

If I manually change the **WHERE** clause entitled **thread_segment** across the values of 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', and 'a5' my landing page updates with the appropriate content in accordance with each of the 5 threads.

My question, is it possible to perhaps mark the href in the HTML email so when that link links to the landing page it could some how interact with the landing page telling it which of the 5 email/email links it is coming from and dynamically alter the thread_segment value appropriately?

I am fairly new to PHP/PDO so I am open to suggestions and/or direction. My current research on the matter has me still researching possibly passing a variable via one of several means, but most of the content I find is in regards to forms.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, just pass the thread_segment in the href of the email, like:
some.url.com/page.php?s=a3
and change your pdo to something like:

```
<?php
   $result = "SELECT body_copy FROM low_engagement WHERE thread_segment = :s";
   $stmt = $connection->prepare($result);
   $stmt->bind_param(':s', $_GET['s']);
   $stmt->execute();
   $body_copy = "";
   while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
       $bodyCopy = $row['body_copy'];
   }
?>
```

Comment: Initially I got a Fatal error that said "Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in..." However I googled that and saw similar code using $stmt->bindParam() and it worked. I don't know enough about php/pdo to know why, but that worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, typed that out from memory and forgot it was camelCase.  Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP GET Variables to pass information using a URL.

e.g. the Link: http://yourlink.org?segment=a1

The `?segment=a1` associates `segment` with the value `a1`, you can add more parameters by seperating with `&` like so: `?segment=a1&language=en`

I am being very explicit with the variable names here, generally you would try to keep the url as short as possible.

You can then access this variable in PHP using `$_GET`:

```
$_GET["segment"]
```

Check out the PHP Docs for further information
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Great! thanks for the insight and documentation. It is much appreciated.